# search and replace with python

Tags: python, search, replace

I am trying to search and replace with python

The file that I want to search and replace is a 3 column tab-separated file with the following sample input:

```
dog walk    1
cat walk    2
pigeon  bark    3
```

The code that I have been using is the following:

```
####open_file
import codecs
input_file=codecs.open("corpus3_tst","r",encoding="utf-8")
lines=input_file.readlines()
for word in lines:
    words=word.rstrip()

    # define method
def replace_all(text, dic):
    for i, j in dic.iteritems():
        text = text.replace(i, j)
    return text

# text for replacement
my_text = words
print my_text

# dictionary with  key:values.
# replace values
reps = {'dog':'ANIMAL', 'cat':'ANIMAL', 'pigeon':'ANIMAL'}

# bind the returned text of the method
# to a variable and print it
txt = replace_all(my_text, reps)
print txt
```

My problem is that it only replaces the  last word with ANIMAL, and it repeats the line again without replacing it.

Output:

```
pigeon  bark    3
ANIMAL  bark    3
```

Does anyone have insight as to where I am going wrong with the script?
I have looked at the documentation for python replace(), as well as similar queries here on stackoverflow and it seems that I am following the documentation, so I don't know where it is that I am going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following, `words` is overwritten in each iteration. After the loop, `words` contains only last line.

```
for word in lines:
    words=word.rstrip()
```

---

Replace following lines:

```
lines=input_file.readlines()
for word in lines:
    words=word.rstrip()
```

with:

```
words = input_file.read().rstrip()
```

---

Using regular expression, the program can be simplified.

```
import codecs
import re

with codecs.open("corpus3_tst","r",encoding="utf-8") as f:
    words = f.read().rstrip()
    pattern = r'dog|cat|pigeon'
    #pattern = '|'.join(map(re.escape, ['dog', 'cat', 'pigeon']))
    print re.sub(pattern, 'ANIMAL', words)
```